# My Honda civic 1.7 cdti steering wheel shakes when braking at high speeds

Tags: honda, brakes, civic

When I'm driving I get a shaking on the steering wheel and on the foot but at high speeds. When I'm travelling between 60-80 mph it's pretty bad,  alot shaking on the steering wheel and even possibly a bit of knocking feeling when braking at high speeds. When driving at low speeds at 30 -40 mph it's smooth when braking and no shaking, and no shaking when driving normally. Shaking only happens when brakes are applied at 40+ mph and gets worse the faster I'm going.

What could be the root cause of this issue?

Comment: Sounds like you have warped rotors.

Comment: If the brakes were warped, the OP would probably getting the shaking at any speed, I'd think.

Comment: Ya may be true, however I had this problem before and it turned out to be that the rotors were warped. While in my own personal case it simply wasn't noticeable enough at low speeds, I just read the OP's post and he suggests it's pretty bad at high speeds, so maybe this is not the same type of situation.

Comment: @Pᴀᴜʟsᴛᴇʀ2 I agree with this answer and their comment. I had the same issue on a 2011 Accord around 50K miles and replacing the rotors fixed the issue. If OP has had bad rotors for a while then the vibration has most likely damaged or warped other parts of the steering and/or suspension system. My car is now at 90K miles and I am starting to feel the vibration again so rotor replacements will be done in the near future.

Comment: Drawninpictures' answer is probably correct and make sure to read my comment on their answer but FWIW, I had an '88 Accord which shook enough to scare me at high speeds. It turned out that the rubber brake line which attaches to the caliper was clogged so the pressure would be easily applied but it took some time for the caliper to fully release again; if ever. Odds are that the brake pad was simply getting worn down enough that the symptom would go away if I didn't brake for long enough. How many miles are on your car?

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange one.

I would suspect warped brakes but it should still cause some feeling even at low speeds. Does the car kind of jerk to a stop when coming up to a stop light? as if you were pressing and letting go of the brake slightly? The low speed vibrations could be masked by power steering especially if that power steering is drive by wire.

another way to check is jack up the front of the car and have someone lightly touch the brake just enough so you can spin the tire by hand but the brake still rubs. if it gets harder and easier than it is definitely a warped disk.

it could be the torque from the brake is loading up a suspension part and letting go. To check this see if any rubber suspension pieces are bad or if anything is loose looks worn or feels worn.

Check to make sure the caliper and pads are installed correctly and bolted down tight.

Lastly it could be your ABS especially if you are braking hard. but it could be malfunctioning or stuck in some safety mode. I would expect the ABS light to turn on on your dash if this was the case.

Last thing is it could be the cv joint in one of your axle shafts is worn out. when the car is putting power into it it will tighten up and might center itself where it is balanced but when you are coasting or applying brakes it could fall into a different position where it is no longer centered causing a vibration.